# Htaccess form POST doesn't work?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a form with an action that redirects to a page;
`<form method="post" action="active">`

The "active" page is a rewritten rule;
`RewriteRule ^active$ active_form-sec.php`

The page with the form is also a RewriteRule.

The problem is, everytime I submit the form and I get on the active page, the POSTs are empty.
How can I fix this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the rewriterule you are using, it's the likely culprit

Comment: That rewriteRule shouldn't be dropping POSTs. Strange. What does a `print_r($_POST)` yield?

Comment: all requests will start with a '/', that re-write rule shouldn't catch anything should it?

Comment: @Pekka; The `print_r($_POST)` is empty. I changed it back to the .php file, but the array is still empty, what could possibly go wrong? Is it because of the `<base...` tag I added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Are you sure about `active_form-sec.php` is called when you hit the submit button?
- If so what do you have when you do `print_r($_POST)`?
- If `active-form-sec.php` isn't called, your mod_rewrite isn't working properly
- If you got an empty array, there's a possibility something is wrong with your inputs (hint: missing `name` attributes)

Debug done.

Comment: It was working perfectly, until I used the htaccess RewriteRule. So I think it has something to do with that. It also redirects to the right page, but when I `echo $_POST`, all strings are empty.

Comment: @Jay Wit note: you can't echo $_POST since it's an array. Btw it'd be useful to look insode Apache logs.

Comment: Yes, I `echo $_POST['var'];` but I just wrote that as an example. And I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @Jay try `print_r($_POST);`. The RewriteRule you show should not drop POST variables. Only those that do a header redirect (causing the browser to load a new page) do.

Comment: @Pekka; `print_r($POST);` is empty, but the htaccess isn't the problem I think. I changed it all back to .php and it still won't work, is it because of the `<base...` tag I added?

Answer (score 0):

that's probably because the .htaccess doens't collect the form data.

Why not doing it like this:

```
<form method="post" action="active_form-sec.php">
```

Comment: Because it isn't as nice looking :)

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

**.htaccess:**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks<br />
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^POST<br />
RewriteRule ^form-posting/?$ posting.php [L,NC]
```

**form.php:**

```
form method="post" action="form-posting"
```

**posting.php:**

```
print_r($_POST);
```

I have tried this code and it works.